# Azure Domain Services Attributes

Tags: azure, ldap, azure-active-directory

Anyone know if the attribute names change when using Azure Domain Services LDAP?  I have a application that authenticates off LDAP and pulls in the users name and email.  But upon switching to Azure Domain Services my authentication still works fine but none of the attributes are defined (ex: givenname, sn, mail, etc)

Comment: Are you sure that this is not an access control issue?

Comment: Ah good catch, that was the issue the account I was using did not have high enough access into Azure AD.

Comment: This is also my question but do you have subscription in Azure or are you using a free trial?